# Can code in library be located at a specific address?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, embedded

I am working on a cmake C/C++ embedded project.  I have an application that is cross platform.  It will run on a PC based simulator as well as an embedded (STM32) target.  A common hardware abstraction layer allows this.

Ideally I wanted to have a library for the target specific HAL e.g. one when built when compiling for STM32, another when compiling for PC).  This would be linked to the application.  Although I have no real need for it to be a separate library.

Where I am getting stuck is that the HAL library for STM32 contains the startup code (asm) for the STM32.  When the HAL library is built and linked, the startup code disappears.  I can directly include the startup code in the application and it is linked and located correctly, but now I need a special case in the application to include that file if building for STM32.

The project folder structure looks like:

```
- TheProject
 - Applications
  - TheMainApplication
    ApplicationSource.c
    CMakeLists.txt   (add_executable, add sources, link HAL library)
- HAL
 - Embedded
  - STM32
   STM32SpecificCode.c
   STM32StartupCode.s
   CMakeLists.txt (add_library(STM32) target_sources(*.c, *.s))
 - PC
  - PC Specific
 CMakeLists.txt (add_library(HAL) if(STM32) add_subdirectory(STM32) link STM32 library else if PC ...)
CMakeLists.txt (project(myproj) add_subdirectory(HAL) add_subdirectory(Applications/TheMainApplication) )
```

There are actually more combinations of targets and options than I have mentioned here but wanted to keep it simple for example sake.

It may be my lack of cmake knowledge on how to use sub folders that is making this hard for me, or bad project structure!  I would really appreciate some advice or feedback on how to structure this so that STM32 specific files remain with STM32 code and avoid special cases in the application makefile if possible.  Or any other relevant advice.

Thanks

Comment: Which language, C or C++ (you have both tags)?  They are distinct languages. The C++ language allows you to overload functions and methods.  Many compilers may perform *name mangling* when linking with libraries and other modules (object files).

Comment: Where is your linker instruction file?  Many linkers for embedded systems allow you to define *segments* and assign files or libraries to the segment.  You can also assigned fixed addresses to the segments.  Otherwise, there is no guarantee on the order of the code (addresses may vary on each compilation).

Comment: Include the linker file or at least how you are using it. What tool chain is in use? I assume gcc. CMake does not do the compiling or linking.

Comment: Create a section placed at a specific address in the linker script where to put the `.o` file of your library.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for your comment, this project uses both C and C++ all over the place with appropriate 'extern C' interfaces where needed.  In this particular example, the HAL library has a basic C interface.  The linker file is located in the STM 32 code folder but given to the linker in the main CMakeLists.txt file.  Sorry, I know this example lacks all the details but was trying to keep it simple.

Comment: @Gerhard thanks also for your comment.  I may not have been clear in that this project compiles and links and locates correctly IF I include the startup code at the main application level.  If the startup code is compiled into the HAL library, it also all compiles and links correctly, but the startup code is not located, in fact it doesn't get linked in at all, presumably because it is never called from anywhere in the main application.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning something such as an ARM vector table to a specific address is indeed done with linker sections on gcc-style toolchains as several have mentioned in comments.  The desired linker section is flagged with a directive in the source and then that section is targeted to a particular region in the linker script.

Linker scripts are nearly invariably target unique.  Even if they were not, it is theoretically not a problem for them to assign the location of a section that is unused by any code.

Taking a step back to what you really seem to be trying to figure out, a build system producing native executables will invariably have to include target unique portions.  Different toolchains and targets require different flags and inputs.  Pretty much invariably you will need some level of difference in the set of source files used.

So generally what you do is organize your build system to group the functional sources that are common to all targets along with their common dependencies.

Then you have a portion for each target that pulls in the common sources, adds target unique ones like I/O routines (or mocks) built from source, and provides the appropriate build rules.  Part of the last is passing appropriate flags, prebuilt libraries to be linked in, and where used specifying the linker script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  After re-reading my question (that I wrote in a hurry last Friday night!), I realised I actually asked two separate questions.  One about project structure and one about why startup code was not located correctly when compiled into a library!